# Phonegap html5 video not playing

Tags: ios, html, cordova, video

I am trying to play a video in a phonegap app in an iPad.

This video is giving me the error:

```
MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED
```

The video I am trying to play is not local, when I used curl -I on that video this is the info it brings:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 13 Jan 2015 19:56:03 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 12939401
Last-Modified: Thu, 20 Nov 2014 18:11:31 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=45
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

I also tried to load another video from an external website, and it did work (it is also an mp4).

My phonegap version is 3.5.0.0

As far as I see I am getting an mp4, which is supported, can anyone see anything wrong in here?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this is helpful for someone. Be careful to encode your videos for mobile with a **Baseline profile**.

It seems that video was encoded with a simple profile. Safari mobile browsers only support natively videos with the following characteristics:

> Safari on iOS (including iPad) currently supports **MPEG-4 video (Baseline profile)** and QuickTime movies encoded with **H.264 video (Baseline profile)** and one of the supported audio types.

As it says in this page:

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the server supports partial requests, as I've noticed that this is a requirement for iOS.

Copy the video URL into a Chrome browser, hit F12 -> network tab to view requests, then reload.  You should see something like this:

```
GET    200 OK
GET    206 PARTIAL CONTENT
GET    206 PARTIAL CONTENT
...
```

This tells you that the server supports partial content requests, which is good.

If you are serving up the video yourself via a service (rather than statically), you'll need to support this feature explicitly in your server-side code.  For example, an ASP.NET Web API tutorial is here:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-web-api-and-http-byte-range-support/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you made the same error of me, I spent a lot of time trying to configurate apache with Access-Control-Allow-Origin... but finally I realize that I'm using nginx, so the header must be modiefied on nginx:

add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";