# HTML video returns MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED error after playing for a while

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I am trying to play a video streamed by a third party using the HTML5 video player in Chrome Mobile, the problem I am facing is that the video can play for some time while it's minimized and after a while it decides to quit and return a **MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED** - audio/video not supported error; the problem happens much faster when I switch from minimised to maximised then back to minimised over and over again. It also seems to happen faster if I continuously tap on the video itself, I have also hidden the default controls and use my own custom ones.

What could be causing this issue ? I try the same thing in Safari with the QuickTime player and the video feed does no die

EDIT: Did some more digging around and found this: 
[Android HLS video mime type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178321/android-hls-video-mime-type)

I receive a playlist m3u8 file but my request link does not have m3u8 in it whatsoever but should the video even be playing if the m3u8 keyword isn't there ? I am also testing this on an android 4.4.4

Comment: "I am trying to play a video streamed by a third party" please provide more information about the third party software you are using.

Comment: Well the stream is being provided by these guys http://unas.tv/index.php?page=services&sub=webservices; I'm just using their feed to play the video

Comment: I face same problem on Opera desktop , so I download the video using `youtube-dl` and is success grab the video source .

Answer (score 2):

Specifying the correct MIME type is worth a try. However, there's one other thing that caught me out (with iOS anyway): check that the server hosting the video supports `206 Partial Content` requests correctly.  I posted about debugging this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33755752/188926).

Answer (score 1):

If your using FireFox and getting the SRC not supported, I went threw the codes on some of the players at sites I like to view, I found that the Adobe Flash Player will solve the Problem, FF uses the VLC plugins, but with the current updates on FF with the VLC on HTLM5 players you might get a SRC error code, you need the Adobe Flash Player.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched your error code on internet and i have found this:

> MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED (4) The media resource specified by src
>   was not usable. MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED 
>   (5) The encrypted media
>   stream could not be played. This is because of one of the following
>   conditions: A key was not provided and a onmsneedkey handler was not
>   provided The provided key could not be applied. Decryption is not
>   supported for this media data.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So I would say you initialize src wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will investigate this and update on whether or not that was the issue.

Comment: No problem, I hope it helped you out :). Please let me know what the solution was once you have found out (or if this was the solution).

Comment: The initialization is fine, I guess the issue might be deeper

Comment: As it turns out, chrome has issues with HLS and one of these issues is incorrect mime type detection due to chrome's lack of solid support for HLS. 

Sources: 
- http://www.encoding.com/http-live-streaming-hls/
- http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/the-pain-of-live-streaming-on-android/

Comment: You can add the `type` attribute in `<source>`. `<source src="stream" type="application/x-mpegURL">` or `<source src="stream" type="vnd.apple.mpegURL">` in case the server doesn't provide the correct Content-Type in the headers.